# Change img properties (src, alt...) based on AJAX success (and fix my ajax ;) )

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The image link I'm using:

```
echo "<br/><div class='right' id='post" . $id . "'>
<img id='thumb' src='/images/like.png' title='Like it?' alt='Like button' 
          onClick='likeButton(" . $id . ");'>( " . getLikes($id) . " )</div><br/>";
```

and the JavaScript is:

```
function likeButton(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../likes/" + id, 
        type: "post", 
        data: {
            id: id},
        success: function(likes) {
        $('#post' + id).html(likes);
    }}); 
}
```

"likes" is the PHP function that adds the click to the db, and it also returns the number (`getLikes($id)`).

But there's a couple things wrong here. When I click, the image disappears and I'm only left with the number

Instead, I need it to keep showing the image (and the paranthesis around the number) - but change the image src and alt if the PHP function `getLikes($id) == "true"`.

Any takers?

Comment: what does `likes` inside ajax success function gives you ? Also where you have checked `getLikes($id) == "true"` ? didn't see that code in your question

Comment: @Swati likes is the PHP function that adds the "like" to the db, and it also returns the number getLikes($id)

Comment: So,what does ` $('#post' + id).html(likes);` this gives ? i.e : likes ? what does it has in it ? just do `console.log(likes)` and see.

Comment: @Swati it returns the return value of likes() - which is a number coming from getLikes($id). So before click, I have <image> + 'likes' and after click I only have 'likes'

Comment: yes because you are replacing entire div using `.html()` instead just replace the `( " . getLikes($id) . " )` part.

Comment: @Swati Aah yeah I can see that now - how can I change .html(likes) to .html(code-for-entire-div) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing the content of the ENTIRE post, just change the value of the likes:

`( " . getLikes($id) . " )` => `<span class="likes">( " . getLikes($id) . " )</span>`

and

```
$(`#post${id} .likes`).text(`(${likes})`);
```

---

**EDIT: Follow-up question:**

You asked about preventing clicking more than once. You can add a flag to know they have already clicked.

NOTE: This will only one until they reload the page, it's not a great solution if you really want to block them. Your server should prevent it server-side in PHP instead (e.g. check if they have already like it before incrementing the count by user id + post id).

```
function likeButton(id) {
    if ($('#post' + id).hasClass('already-liked')) {
        return;
    }
    $('#post' + id).addClass('already-liked');

    $.ajax({
        url: "../../likes/" + id, 
        type: "post", 
        data: {
            id: id},
        success: function(likes) {
        $('#post' + id).html(likes);
    }}); 
}
```

Comment: What are you supposed to be changing the image attributes to? You cannot check the output of a PHP function unless the output values are computed server-side and comes back in your AJAX response. Regarding: `if the PHP function getLikes($id) == "true"`.

Comment: so how do I do it?

Comment: How are you supposed to know the expected new values for image src/alt? Your question doesn't make that clear. Unless you create an endpoint to get those values via AJAX request, you cannot use PHP as that only executes prior to page load.

Comment: Gotcha. I tried your code but $(`#post${id} .likes`).text(`(${likes})`); - is still replacing the entire div, so I still end up with no image

Comment: That replaces the text value of the item with the `class="likes"`. So unless you added that class your overall post, that wouldn't happen. Are you sure you didn't forget to remove your existing setting of `$('#post' + id).html(likes);` which would reset the entire div?

Comment: My bad - it works now!
Is there anything I can do to prevent people from being able to click more than once?

Comment: I added an update to give you an example of the client-side. But you really should handle that on the server.

Comment: Actually I just did that - just added an if/then to the likes() function so they can click all they want but the data won't update if they click more than once.   HUUUUGE thanks for all your help!!!